# Error: Forbidden Access Message (Drupal-6.x)

Tags: drupal, installation, symlink

I'm new to Drupal and I'm trying to create multiple sites inside Drupal. I'm trying to create a symlink via the command line. I tried going to my browser to run the new installation for the new website, but I receive a message that says **Forbidden Access**.

To create the symlink in the terminal:

```
ln -s ~/Sites/drupal-6.20/sites/sitename2.com
```

My Drupal-6.20 folder is the root directory of my localhost.

In the browser to start the installation I tried:
http://localhost:80/sitename2.com

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the web root should be pointing to the index.php in the Drupal root for *all* of the sites you're hosting on that codebase.

In your case, you are getting an error because there's nothing in the `/sites/yoursite.com` directory that your webserver can run on it's own.

Longer answer: Configuring Drupal for multiple domains takes a little bit more reading and learning that can be summarized in an SO response.

The guide at http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/install/multi-site is a great place to start, and includes links to videos and additional tutorials in case you need additional help.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know drupal that much, but i know other cms. And i think you should check for "permisions tab".
I worked with joomla, which i think is quite simmilar. And the first time you just have to go to http://localhost/. Installation started. And when it finnished, i had to delete installation folder out of localhost root.

But this is for joomla.